# Update table depending on another table values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables accounts table which has a column `name` and accounts_cstm which has columns (`company_name_c` varchar,`first_name_c` varchar,`last_name_c` varchar).
Tables accounts.id and accounts_cstm.id are identical. 
I am trying to create a query that i am going to replace all values in accounts.name(varchar) under circumstances.
If company_name_c has value then replace it with company_name_c OR
If company_name_c is null then replace it with concat first_name_c and last_name_c . I created this query but i get error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'TEST_Launch1'. Any help please ?
```

Below the query:

```
update accounts,(select accounts_cstm.id_c as idc, 
                (case accounts_cstm.company_name_c 
                    WHEN accounts_cstm.company_name_c is not null THEN  accounts_cstm.company_name_c
                    WHEN '' THEN  accounts_cstm.company_name_c
                    ELSE CONCAT(accounts_cstm.first_name_c,' ',accounts_cstm.last_name_c) END) as name1
from accounts_cstm) as accc
SET accounts.name = accc.name1
where accounts.id = accc.idc
```

Comment: Yes its the correct one . Test_Launch is a value

Comment: post the table schema for both tables in question

Comment: are you  sure you don't have trigger related  to update ..  ??  that involve TEST_launch1?

Comment: Yes i am sure about that. TEST_Launch1 is value in company_name_c

Answer (score 0):

I'm newbie myself ... but I guess triggers in mysql could be quite handy . 
here is a link to the introduction of the triggers :
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-triggers.aspx